# operator== for classes inside a variadic template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++20

I have the following class structure:

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Foo {  };
    class Bar {  };
};
```

I need to define `operator==` for `SomeClass<Ts...>::Foo` and `SomeClass<Ts...>::Bar` and I need to make it a friend of both `Foo` and `Bar`. The closest I got this to working is the following:

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Bar;
    class Foo {
        
        friend bool operator==(const Foo&, const Bar&) { 
            return true;
        }
    };
    class Bar { 
        
        friend bool operator==(const Foo&, const Bar&);
    };
};
```

Then I do:

```cpp
SomeClass<int, double>::Foo foo;
SomeClass<int, double>::Bar bar;
foo == bar;
```

This compiles and works fine except for the fact that gcc gives me the warning:

```
warning: friend declaration `bool operator==(const SomeClass<Args>::Foo&, const SomeClass<Args>::Bar&)` declares a non-template function
note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)
```

I kind of understand why this happens (operator== indeed depends on the template parameters of SomeClass), but how do I get rid of it? Adding <> to the second friend declaration, as suggested, only breaks compilation: the friending is no longer recognized and the compiler complaints about access to a private member.

I tried to modify the code according to the [template friend declaration guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends), but that only made things worse:

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass;

template <typename... Args>
bool operator==(const typename SomeClass<Args...>::Foo&, 
                const typename SomeClass<Args...>::Bar&);

template <typename... Args>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Bar;
    class Foo {
        
        friend bool operator==<Args...>(const Foo&, const Bar&);
    };
    class Bar { 
        
        friend bool operator==<Args...>(const Foo&, const Bar&);
    };
};

template <typename... Args>
bool operator==(const typename SomeClass<Args...>::Foo&, 
                const typename SomeClass<Args...>::Bar&) {
    return true;
}
```

Now the weirdest thing happens when I call `foo == bar`:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘SomeClass<int, double>::Foo’ and ‘SomeClass<int, double>::Bar’)
note: candidate: ‘bool operator==(const typename SomeClass<Args ...>::Foo&, const typename SomeClass<Args ...>::Bar&) [with Args = {}; typename SomeClass<Args ...>::Foo = SomeClass<>::Foo; typename SomeClass<Args ...>::Bar = SomeClass<>::Bar]’ (reversed)
note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SomeClass<int, double>::Bar’ to ‘const SomeClass<>::Foo&’
```

I.e. for some weird reason it tries to call the template specification with an empty arguments list and fails. Changing the operator type (to operator+) doesn't help (my idea was, this had something to do with C++20 new rules for comparison operators, but no).

So the questions I have are:

0. What's going on? I'm kind of confused, especially by the second part: why would the compiler try to call the operator for an empty parameter pack?
1. How do I avoid the warning in the first solution?
2. How do I define the operator outside of the class definition properly?

Comment: This is strange that after correcting your code gcc reports an warrning: https://godbolt.org/z/ne3q7o5M4

Comment: @MarekR: Also, that "correction" results in a linker error `undefined reference to 'operator==(SomeClass<int, double>::Foo const&, SomeClass<int, double>::Bar const&)'` :-)

Comment: @MarekR (as a reply to your comment to my deleted answer), I thought modifying the code like I did would fix the linker error, but you're right, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution with `operator==`'s definition outside the class.
There is no warning now, but I had to remove the `friend` qualifier. In order to access `Foo`'s private methods from `Bar`'s functions, declare `Bar` a friend of `Foo` (inside `Foo`). Do likewise for `Bar` if you want to access `Bar`'s members from within `Foo`'s methods.

Perhaps its a step forward. Hopes this helps.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Bar;
    class Foo;
    
    class Foo {
    public:
        friend Bar;
        bool operator==(const Bar&) const;

        void do_something_to_Bar(Bar&);

    private:
        int _foo;
    };

    class Bar {
    public:
        friend Foo;
        bool operator==(const Foo&) const;

        void do_something_to_Foo(Foo&);

    private:
        int _bar;
    };
    
};

template<typename... Args>
bool SomeClass<Args...>::Foo::operator== (const Bar& b) const {
    return b._bar == _foo;
}

template<typename... Args>
bool SomeClass<Args...>::Bar::operator== (const Foo& f) const {
    return f == *this;
}

template<typename... Args>
void SomeClass<Args...>::Bar::do_something_to_Foo(Foo& f) {
    f._foo = 4;
    _bar = 4;
}

template<typename... Args>
void SomeClass<Args...>::Foo::do_something_to_Bar(Bar& b) {
    b._bar = 4;
    _foo = 3;
}

int main() {
    SomeClass<int,float>::Foo foo;
    SomeClass<int,float>::Bar bar;
    
    foo.do_something_to_Bar(bar);
    std::cout << (foo == bar) << '\n';
    std::cout << (bar == foo) << '\n';

    bar.do_something_to_Foo(foo);
    std::cout << (foo == bar) << '\n';
    std::cout << (bar == foo) << '\n';
}
```

The definition of `SomeClass<Args...>::Bar::operator==` does not redefine the operator, but rather uses the definition of `SomeClass<Args...>::Foo::operator==`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the operator to use private members of both classes.

Comment: @rm-rf Private members can be accessed by declaring the classes as friend of each other. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here are the results of some research I did.

In case of the friend in-class definition, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators), what it does is it generates *non-template overloads* of operator==. Thus, it is perfectly fine to reference them from the second friend declaration, and the code itself is correct. This is also why adding "<>" breaks the befriending: the overloads generated by the first definition are not template functions, while the second definition with the "<>" added now refers to some template overload that isn't definded.

Both Clang and MSVC compile that code without any problems, so the warning seems to be a GCC-only thing. I think, it is ok to suppress it.

The alternative would be to make the operator into a template, but unfortunately doing this properly for the parent class template parameters is impossible. This won't compile (see below why):

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Bar;
    class Foo {
        
        template <typename... Ts>
        friend bool operator==(const typename SomeClass<Ts...>::Foo&, 
                               const typename SomeClass<Ts...>::Bar&) { 
            return true;
        }
    };
    class Bar { 
        template <typename... Ts>
        friend bool operator==(const typename SomeClass<Ts...>::Foo&, 
                               const typename SomeClass<Ts...>::Bar&);
    };
};
```

The real alternative here is to trick GCC by making the operator template with some obsolete arguments, that could be deduced. And since default template arguments are forbidden in friend declarations, the only other hack I can think of is to make the operator variadic and use the [fact](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) that *a trailing parameter pack that is not otherwise deduced, is deduced to an empty parameter pack*. This works and emits no warnings in GCC:

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Bar;
    class Foo {
        
        template <typename...>
        friend bool operator==(const Foo&, const Bar&) { 
            return true;
        }
    };
    class Bar { 
        template <typename...>
        friend bool operator==(const Foo&, const Bar&);
    };
};
```

I really see no reason in doing that now, so the best thing to do is to pretend that you never saw this, and that I never wrote this.

---

Now, the second part, the outside definition. The problem here is that, as it turns out, there is no way in C++ to deduce template arguments (pack or not) of a parent class from a nested class.

I.e. a thing like this cannot possibly work:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(typename Parent<T>::Child) { }

foo(Parent<int>::Child{});
```

There even was a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0293r0.pdf) to resolve this issue, but it was declined.

Defining `operator==` as a template function in my example above has exactly this problem: once the operator is called for `SomeClass<int, double>::Foo` and `SomeClass<int, double>::Bar`, the argument deduction is impossible (though the definition itself is correct), thus the compilation fails. This is also the answer to my first question: since the deduction is impossible, a parameter pack is deduced as an empty pack. Not at all what I intended.

The only workaround I came up with is to define the operator for the template non-nested arguments, and then restrict them. I am going to use C++20 concepts for this, although I think a SFINAE solution could be just as fine.

This works exactly as intended:

```cpp
template <typename...>
class SomeClass;

template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsSomeClass = false;

template <typename... Args>
constexpr bool IsSomeClass<SomeClass<Args...>> = true;

template <typename T, typename U>
concept IsProperFooBar = requires {
  typename T::Parent;
  typename U::Parent;
  requires std::same_as<typename T::Parent, typename U::Parent>;
  requires IsSomeClass<typename T::Parent>;
  requires std::same_as<std::decay_t<T>, typename T::Parent::Foo>;
  requires std::same_as<std::decay_t<U>, typename U::Parent::Bar>;
};

template <typename T, typename U> requires IsProperFooBar<T, U>
bool operator==(const T&, const U&);

template <typename... Args>
class SomeClass {
public:
    class Foo {
    public:
      using Parent = SomeClass;

    private:
      template <typename T, typename U> requires IsProperFooBar<T, U>
      friend bool operator==(const T&, const U&);
    };

    class Bar {
    public:
      using Parent = SomeClass;

    private:
      template <typename T, typename U> requires IsProperFooBar<T, U>
      friend bool operator==(const T&, const U&);
    };
};

template <typename T, typename U> requires IsProperFooBar<T, U>
bool operator==(const T&, const U&) {
    return true;
}
```

The only issue I see with this solution is that there is now a universal template `operator==`, so the concept will be checked every time you call `==` for anything, which may slow down compilation and emit unnecessary concept-not-satisfied diagnostic messages for other things.
On the plus side, there is no need in forward-declaring `class Bar` anymore, so at least I got that going for me, which is nice :-)